# Visual Studio Solution Style using CMakelists

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I'd make a solution on visual studio and I wish to 'convert' it to CMakelists.

The solution is a folder called Silex and contains 3 projects: Engine, Game, Sandbox.

The Engine project is built in dll/lib files and the Game and Sandbox depends on this dll/lib files.

I want to make the same thing using CMakelists. I want the CMake to built the Engine into libs and use them into the Game and Sandbox projects.

Comment: Can you please give an example of what you have tried and why it didn't fit your needs or what problems you have encountered?

Comment: I tryed to create a CMakelists file for each project, one for the solution, one for the game, one for the sandbox.
The solution one add subforders that is each of the projects folder. And the CMakelists for the project folders used the add_executable to make the lib. But it didnt work

Comment: Sounds good. What do you mean with "didn't work"? And it sounds that you already have a [mcve] you could add to your question.

Comment: It can't find the headers of the Engine project.
In the Engine Project I have a header file called Engine.h that contains all the Engine's includes. I want that when I build the Engine lib the Game can see those headers.